# Gmail account recovery

Tags: gmail, account-recovery

I'm trying to recover my account. I still have the phone number associated with my account. However, when it texts me Gmail recovery code to that number, it still won't let me in... it makes no sense.

Answer (score -2):

Try with alternative email address if you have provided when signing up. or else try recovering by following step on mobile

1. Go-to settings
2. google account
3. Security
4. step verification

Hope it will work out.